# Kafka Producer API - onCompletion

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Trying to understand the Java producer API . onCompletion means what ? Help me understand for the same .

Reference : 
https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

```
ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>("the-topic", key, value);
 producer.send(myRecord,
               new Callback() {
                   public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                       if(e != null) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                       } else {
                          System.out.println("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
                       }
                   }
               });
```

Answer (score 2):

In method

```
producer.send(ProducerRecord<K,V> record, new Callback() {
                   public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {...}
  });
```

callback is invoked once the send has been acknowledged. The callback executes in a background I/O thread so it should be fast (don’t block it)

By default, the send is asynchronous and this method will return immediately once the record has been stored in the buffer of records waiting to be sent. This allows sending many records in parallel without blocking to wait for the response after each one.

Send returns the RecordMetadata that specifies the partition where the record is sent to, the offset assigned to it and the timestamp.

This is an asynchronous approach while you can do the same using synchronous way :

`producer.send(record).get();`